# jQuery Waypoints not working with absolutely positioned div

Tags: jquery, html, css, iscroll, jquery-waypoints

I am using the iScroll library which creates its own scrolling. This is an issue because the body must look like this:
`<body>

<div id="wrapper">

<div id="scroller">

*page content*

</div></div></body>`

This is a problem because #wrapper has to be `position: absolute;` in order for iScroll to work, but waypoints are no longer triggered.

Suggestions? Can I change waypoints.js to look at #wrapper or #scroller instead?
Thanks

Comment: Full code? Live demo? Please, allow us to help you

Answer (score 0):

Waypoints doesn't work with iScroll out of the box because iScroll doesn't fire `scroll` events. It uses margin/cssTransforms to accomplish the faux scrolling.

Comment: Okay, so do you have a suggestion on how to alter waypoints so that it looks at elements in the viewport? It seems like it is trying to do that, but nothing seems to be triggering.